# Strange behaviour with List after unity reload script assemblies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity and C#, and I have a strange behaviour each time I update my scripts and after Unity "Reload script assemblies".

The first time I run the game after the reload, I have errors that I will explain below, but after that, I can reload the game without problem.

I have a list like :

```
public List<Task> QueuedTasks = new();
```

I populate my list with :

```
Task task = new Task{ Param = param};
TaskSystem.Instance.QueuedTasks.Add(task);
```

So in my list I can only have Task objects, but after reload assembly, I have null values in this list, because If I add this debug code, I can see the debug log :

```
foreach(var test in TaskSystem.Instance.QueuedTasks) {
    if (test is null) {
         Debug.Log("task is null");
    }
}
```

**This is the first weird problem, why after Unity "reload script assemblies" I have null values in my list ?**

And the second problem, is when I try to remove an element from this list after unity "reload script assembly", I have the error

> "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
> non-negative and less than the size of the collection but contains
> true"

I remove element from my list with :

```
QueuedTasks.Remove(task);
```

And If I add a debug before and check if my list contains the element, the Contains function return true :

```
 // I CANT SEE THIS DEBUG, BECAUSE CONTAINS RETURN TRUE
 if (!QueuedTasks.Contains(task)) {
      Debug.Log("QueuedTasks not contain task, its weird");
 }

 // BUT HERE I HAVE ArgumentOutOfRangeException
 QueuedTasks.Remove(task);
```

**This is my second problem, why Contains return true, and Remove throw the ArgumentOutOfRangeException ?**

Thanks

---

Here you can find more code, related to this problem (and simplified, I removed a lots of useless code for the purpose of this topic), this is the "entry point", where I call the DequeueTask function, I can have multiple instance of WorkerTaskAI, so I can run multiple DequeueTask at the same time :

```
 public class WorkerTaskAI : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Worker _worker;
        private float _waitingTimerDequeueTask;

        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            _waitingTimerDequeueTask -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (_waitingTimerDequeueTask <= 0) {
                _waitingTimerDequeueTask = TaskSystem.REQUEST_NEXT_TASK_DELAY;
                DequeueTask(_worker);
            }
        }
```

The DequeueTask function (with a commented lock doesn’t look like it’s working) :

```
 public async void DequeueTask(Worker worker)
        {
            if (TaskSystem.Instance.QueuedTasks.Count > 0) {
                Task task;

                //lock (TaskSystem.Instance.Lock) {
                    foreach(var test in TaskSystem.Instance.QueuedTasks) {
                        if (test is null) {
                            Debug.Log("task is null");
                        }
                    }

                    // HERE I HAVE MORE CONDITIONS TO ORDER THE LIST BY TASK PRIORITY, BUT USELESS FOR THE PROBLEM
                    var tasks = TaskSystem.Instance.QueuedTasks.Where(t => !t.IsBeingChecked).ToList();

                    if (tasks.Count() == 0) {
                        return;
                    }

                    task = tasks.First();
                    task.IsBeingChecked = true;
                //}

                 await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => DoDequeueTask(task, worker));
            }
    }
```

The DoDequeueTask :

```
 private void DoDequeueTask(Task task, Worker worker)
        {         
             if (I CAN DEQUEUE MY TASK) {
                 if (!Tasks.Contains(task)) {
                     if (!QueuedTasks.Contains(task)) {
                        Debug.Log("QueuedTasks not contain task, its weird");
                      }

                QueuedTasks.Remove(task);
                Tasks.Add(task);
            }
              } else {
                   task.IsBeingChecked = false;
              }
```

Task and TaskSystem :

```
public class TaskSystem : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public static TaskSystem Instance;

    public List<Task> Tasks = new();
    public List<Task> QueuedTasks = new();
    public readonly object Lock = new();

    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

public class Task
{
```

Comment: Most probably there's more than one thread that is accessing `TaskSystem.Instance.QueuedTasks` collection. In your last example with `if` and `remove` there's another thread that changes the collection while execution moves from the `if` to `remove()` call

Comment: Hum, I have multiple threads yes, I'm using async for some parts of my code, related to this. But if its a thread problem, why I have theses bugs only the first time I run the game after unity "reload script assemblies" ?

Comment: You haven't shown how you run these codes and how you asynchronously modify the list. There are too many possibilities for these problems if you don't handle threads well. Do these problems still exist if you just use single thread?

Comment: And what are `Task` and `TaskSystem.Instance`? Are they serializable classes?

Comment: And If I remove the async  from "async void DequeueTask", and call DequeueTask directly without the "await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run.....", it seems to be working

Comment: I tried to add locks everytime I access my list, and it seems to be working

Comment: If you want to operate the same list in multiple threads, you need to use lock.